# Daemonizing a C program and location of copying the file

Tags: linux, monit

I have to run a C program using monit. so I had to demonize it. what i did was i took a daemon template made some changes and arrived at this file as below, which is a script file:

```
# Source function library
. /home/stallions/queue.c

# Do preliminary checks here, if any
#### START of preliminary checks #########


##### END of preliminary checks #######

# Handle manual control parameters like start, stop, status, restart, etc.

case "$1" in
  start)
    # Start daemons.

    echo -n $"Starting queue daemon: "
    echo
    daemon queue
    echo
    ;;

  stop)
    # Stop daemons.
    echo -n $"Shutting down queue: "
    killproc queue
    echo

    # Do clean-up works here like removing pid files from /var/run, etc.
    ;;
  status)
    status queue

    ;;
  restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;

  *)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
    exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

when i execute this file # ./queue
i get errors

```
         # line 8: 'void fifoinit(int size)'
         # line 8: syntax error near unexpected token
```

I am not sure what should be the source function library path. I have given it the path where my original queue.c exits which i wanted to run it as a daemon. Can you ell me should there be anything else to be done to run this as a daemon and how to correct the errors?

Comment: You obviously don't have a bit of a clue what you are doing. `.c` files have to be compiled, they can't be sourced into a bash script.

Comment: I actually have to run them using monit...so when i asked it yesterday here all replied that i have to demonize it so that i could run it. so thats what I did....so how do i run them using monit then?

Comment: You have to learn so much I don't even know where to begin with. You write a program in C, compile it and then you can use a script like the one you copied here to demonize it, or you can let the C program handle that itself and you use this script to start/stop the demon. This is all way off-topic here.

Comment: I am sorry if its off topic, but i really need to know i have a project deadline tomorrow. I will tell you what I did clearly.

Comment: Then you are not qualified for this project and should hand it over to someone who is. I am sorry, but you are lacking so much that we just can't fix this on a site like [SF].

Comment: Pastebin the code for queue.c

Comment: I am sorry if its off topic, but i really need to know i have a project deadline tomorrow. I will tell you what I did clearly. 
1. First I wrote a simple C program in VI and then I compiled it using gcc and got the output.
2. Next I wanted to run it using monit so I had to give a path in monit control file for this C program which i gave it as below: 
check process queue.c
matching "queue.c"
start program = "/home/stallions/queue.c"
stop program = "killall queue.c"
3. Then what I did was went to the init.d location and created the file above mentioned in the question. This is where i ended up

Comment: @balu, you're missing the point.  C programs must be compiled before they can be run.  You'd need to compile it to a binary file with gcc first, then execute the binary file with monit.  use www.pastebin.com and show us the content of queue.c

Comment: Yes I have pasted it in pastebin.com done it. I did compile the file using gcc and got the file a.out

Comment: You should probably take a look at man monit.

It's said, monit -d to demonize it.

So, basically, you just have to:

1°/- Compile your C program, we will call it queue <-- BINARY AND NOT queue.c
2°/- Take a look at man monit to be able to understand how it work.
3°/- Write a bash script which will simply call monit with the correct parameters, so in your case, it should be something like:

monit -d -c "/somewhere/MyControlFile" monitor all

4°/- configure your init script to launch at the correct level.

Comment: Right.. You've pastebinned it, but you've failed to paste a link to the pastebin into the comments here.. You sir, are an idiot.

Comment: its just with the name queue anyways: http://pastebin.com/mb2rH6tV

Comment: Even if you did get it to execute through Monit, it'd more than likely fail because your application needs an interactive console.  You've got `sscanf` calls for user input.  You can't run a daemon with user input.

Comment: What the hell was this written for?  Just *why*? If I wanted a queue in my application, i'd use ZeroMQ, or RabbitMQ, or someone elses known-good working code.

Comment: Actually, I'd be surprised if this even compiled, and didn't leak memory or segfault.

Comment: @TomO'Connor the program queue.c is just an example program. that is not what i need....i need to run a c program in monit. Let it be just a simple hello world program.....and it did get executed with an output also. *all i need is run some processes using monit*

Comment: So why complicate the issue with your inability to write C? A list of Monit configuration examples can be found here. http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples

Answer (score 3):

You need first to compile your C program. The following command can do it if your program does not depend on any library to be linked with:

```
$ gcc -o queue queue.c
```

This will produce the binary `queue` if it goes well. It seems your script is trying to execute this binary. You need just to make sure to set the correct path.

Don't source the C program into your shell script. Remove the line:

```
. /home/stallions/queue.c
```

Comment: I have compiled it and got the file: a.out
Where shold i set the path in the script file of queue

Comment: You need to rename it using `mv a.out /some/path/queue`. Choose a valid path for `/some/path`. Then, use the same path in your shell script.

Comment: I did what you said and now i got the binary file also.
I gave the path of this binary in the script. when i run the script it says cannot execute binary file

Comment: Did you bother to set the execute flag on the binary with `chmod`?

Comment: chmod 755 queue?

Comment: I did chmod......still it gives cannot execute binary file.

I executed it directly from its location and i got the output but when i am trying to execute from the script it isn't

Comment: @growse Its still not executing.
 I have given the path to binary file....it says cannot execute binary file